# Android - Correct way to write repository when app needs to periodically sync data with server

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, repository-pattern

What would be the best way to implement repository pattern:

[image: Architecture]

In the case when the app needs to sync with the server in some scheduled time, not on every UI data refresh/call to the repository?

Should my repository, in that case, return always data from the database without bothering with REST API calls? Should I put my API calls into some WorkManager/background service?

In that way, the repository would be responsible to return local data, and some other service would be responsible to sync data with the server.
Is that a bad architecture?

Should I use another design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Define a LiveData in your repository and whenever the repository method called, post the new data to it and on the other hand, your view get this liveData from viewModel and observe that (Recommended MVVM).
Now when you get new data from API, your liveData will update and all views are also updated together.

Notice: Be careful don't define your liveData in viewModel or every time create new a liveData.